# run a task if something Worked Python3

Tags: python, python-3.6

This is my script. What I want to do is that I want to run the print function if the call function worked.

```
from subprocess import call
from os import system as S

Com1 = 'sudo xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 
1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync'
Command1 = Com1.split()
Com2 = 'sudo xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1368x768_60.00"'
Command2 = Com2.split() 
COMMAND1 = call(Command1)
COMMAND2 = call(Command2)
print('\n\n\t\nscreen resolution successfully changed Script By : My name '.title())
print('\n\n')
```

This is a pseudocode of this:

```
if COMMAND1 and COMMAND2 worked:
  print('It WorkEd')
else:
  print('IT DIDNT WORK')
```

Can someone please help me. I am very new in Python.

Answer (score 0):

The `call` function returns the exit code of the command. If the return code is 0, that means the command ran successfully, otherwise the command failed. So in order to achieve what you want, you can do something like this:

```
if COMMAND1 == 0 and COMMAND2 == 0:
  print "It worked"
else:
  print "It didn't work"
```